# Sorting with Selection

Tags: java, sorting

I've just started learning about `sorting` and my `class` is currently working with selection. For my assignment, I have to sort a `number list` in increasing order and show with the `array` looks like and the current # of comparisons, and we have to do it on paper.

The numbers are:

```
90, 8, 7, 56, 123, 235, 9, 1, 653.
```

So far, this is what I have (sorted list is in bold):

```
90|8|7|56|123|235|9|1|653



 # of comparisons: 0

---

**1**|8|7|56|123|235|9|90|653 

 # of comparisons: 1

---

**1**|**7**|8|56|123|235|9|90|653 

 # of comparisons: 2
```

---

This is basically the point at which I have a question. Because 8 is already in the correct place, would a comparison still take place? Or would it go straight to the next value? So, would it be:

```
---

**1**|**7**|**8**|56|123|235|9|90|653 

 # of comparisons: 3

---

or would it be: 

---

**1**|**7**|**8**|**9**|123|235|56|90|653 

 # of comparisons: 3

---
```

I believe the former is correct, but I just wanted to ask you guys to make sure I'm understanding this properly.

Comment: I doubt that this is correct. How did you get from the original array to the first step (with 1 in its proper position) using only one comparison? With 9 elements, you needed to do 8 comparisons to discover that 1 was the smallest number.

Comment: EDIT: OH, I see what you mean. I just realized my number of comparisons are totally off. So I guess now I'm just wondering about the 8 part - would that add to the # of comparisons or not?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I just realized I was doing the # of comparisons completely wrong. I edited that comment to what I'm asking now

Comment: I think that after the first step, the number of comparisons should be 8. After the second step, the number of comparisons would be 8 + 7 = 15 (there were 8 numbers in the unsorted portion and you needed 7 more comparisons to find the smallest number). And so forth.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That cleared things up.

Comment: You may find http://sorting.at to be useful (change it so you only have the selection sort and insertion sort as options).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps if you understand how the smallest element in the list is selected.  An efficient way to do this is to start by assuming that the first unsorted element is the smallest and then iterate through the remaining unsorted elements testing this hypothesis.

```
90, 8, 7, 56, 123, 235, 9, 1, 653
```

If this is your list, then you begin by assuming 90 is the smallest.  Then you compare 90 to 8.  8 is smaller than 90, so you update your hypothesis to be that 8 is the smallest.  That makes 1 comparison.  You compare 8 to 7.  7 is smaller, so now your hypothesis is that 7 is the smallest.  2 comparisons.  You compare 7 to 56.  7 is smaller, so your hypothesis remains unchanged.  3 comparisons.  It takes 8 comparisons to work your way through the list and determine that 1 is the smallest.

Now that you know that 1 is the smallest you swap it with the first element in the list.

```
1, 8, 7, 56, 123, 235, 9, 90, 653
```

Now 1 is in the correct place and you do not have to worry about it again.  Now you need to sort the following list.

```
8, 7, 56, 123, 235, 9, 90, 653
```

7 comparisons later, you determine that 7 is the smallest element in the list.  You swap it with the first element.

```
7, 8, 56, 123, 235, 9, 90, 653
```

Now you need to sort the following list.

```
8, 56, 123, 235, 9, 90, 653
```

Keep in mind that even though 8 is already in the correct sorted location, *you do not know that 8 is the smallest element in the list until you have compared it to **every other item** in the unsorted list.*  Therefore you must still make 6 comparisons in order to determine that 8 is the smallest element.  However, since 8 is the first element in the list, you do not need to swap it.  You can just leave it where it is.

```
8, 56, 123, 235, 9, 90, 653
```

Now you need to sort the following list.

```
56, 123, 235, 9, 90, 653
```

And so forth.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time!

Comment: No problem.  I remember when I was first learning this stuff.  It takes some time to get used to thinking the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You should count the number of comparisons and the number of swaps separately. If there are `n` elements in the unsorted part of the array, then you need `n-1` comparisons to discover which one is the smallest. Once you know which is the smallest, then you may or may not need a swap. So I think the progress should be as follows:

> 90|8|7|56|123|235|9|1|653
>    # of comparisons: 0
>    # of swaps: 0

---

> **1**|8|7|56|123|235|9|90|653
>    # of comparisons: 8
>    # of swaps: 1

---

> **1**|**7**|8|56|123|235|9|90|653
>    # of comparisons: 15
>    # of swaps: 2

---

> **1**|**7**|**8**|56|123|235|9|90|653
>    # of comparisons: 21
>    # of swaps: 2

---

> **1**|**7**|**8**|**9**|123|235|56|90|653
>    # of comparisons: 26
>    # of swaps: 3

etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

If by "comparison" you mean a single pass through, then the former is correct. While you can eyeball the numbers and know that 8 is in the correct place, the algorithm isn't that smart, and still has to review the rest of the numbers in the unsorted portion of the list to make certain.

You may ask "But 8 comes after 7, so how could there be something smaller?" There could be duplicates (another 7) in the unsorted list.

[Wikipedia Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)